# Recommended way to run sequential background Tasks in JAVAFX in given order

Tags: javafx, task, execution, sequential

Because of the way I modularized my code, I have several background (non-JAVAFX) Tasks that I wish to execute from my JAVAFX controller sequentially in a specified order. I would like the next Task to start as soon as possible after the previous Task finishes.  I searched for examples, but I think they did not guarantee that the treads would be executed in the specified order.  I also know that I generally should not try to make the FX thread wait or loop to check the progress of the task lest the GUI freeze. Being a beginner, I do not know how to implement my goal. Suppose I have these Task: task1, task2, task3. Any general recommendations on how to run task1, then task2, then task3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a single-thread executor to execute the tasks:

```
ExecutorService exec = Exectors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

You probably want to scope this as an instance variable in the class that creates the tasks.

Then just do:

```
Task<Something> task1 = ... ;
Task<Something> task2 = ... ;
Task<Something> task3 = ... ;

exec.submit(task1);
exec.submit(task2);
exec.submit(task3);
```

Comment: I found for my application to terminate properly I have to use shutdown(). However, my tasks are created in a method that the user is able to run repeatedly. Thus, I found it necessary to instantiate exec in that method, and not use it as class instance variable. Generally are there any disadvantages to its not being a class instance variable?